# how to set default item like "Please select one" in p:selectOneMenu with object from database?

Tags: java, primefaces

i have a p:selectOneMenu filled with objects from database.When page is looaded first,
the default item of selectOneMenu must be "please select one" in string type( other items of selectOneMenu are in object type.) When page is loaded first, one data in object type from database is visible as default.I don't want this.how to set default item like "Please select one" in p:selectOneMenu with object from database?

```
 <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
            template="layout.xhtml">

  <ui:define name="pageContent">
    <h:form id="silYapilandirmaForm" prependId="true">
                 <p:panel id="silYapilandirmaPanel" header="#{etiketler.silYapilandirma}"         collapsed="true" toggleable="true" >
            <p:tabView id="tabView" dynamic="false" activeIndex="0">

                      <p:tab title="#{etiketler.silIslemleri}" id="silIslemleriTab">
                    <p:outputPanel id="silIslemleriPanel">


                        <h:panelGrid  id="eshsSecPanelGrid" columns="3" >
                            <h:outputText value="#{etiketler.eshsSertifika}:*" />  

                            <p:selectOneMenu  id="silYapilandirmaSelect"  value="#{silYapilandirmaView.seciliEshsSertifika}" effect="fade" effectDuration="100" style="width: 205px"  converter="#{entityConverter}">

                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Please select one" itemValue="#{null}"/>


                                <f:selectItems value="#{silYapilandirmaView.eshsSertifikaList}" var="eshsSertifika" 
                                                       itemLabel="#{eshsSertifika.sertifikaKodAdi}" itemValue="#{eshsSertifika}" />



                                <p:ajax process="@this" event="change" update="eshsSecPanelGrid,silIslemleriPanel"  listener="#{silYapilandirmaView.addListener()}"  />
                            </p:selectOneMenu>

                            <h:outputText value=""/>

                            <h:outputText value="#{etiketler.eshsSertifika}:" />
                            <h:inputText  value="#{silYapilandirmaView.seciliEshsSertifika.sertifikaKodAdi}" disabled="true" size="30"/>


                            <h:outputText value=""/>
                            <h:outputText value="#{etiketler.silUretimBaslangicSaati}:* " />   
                            <p:inputMask id="silUretimBaslangicSaatiInputMask"  value="#{silYapilandirmaView.seciliEshsSertifika.silUretimBaslangicSaati}" mask="99:99:99" size="30" />
                            <p:message for="silUretimBaslangicSaatiInputMask" display="text" />

                            <h:outputText value="#{etiketler.silUretimBaslangicPeriyodu}:* "  />
                            <p:inputMask  maxlength="4" mask="99?99" id="periyotInputMask"  size="30" value="#{silYapilandirmaView.seciliEshsSertifika.silUretimPeriyodu}" >  
      </p:inputMask> 
                            <p:message for="periyotInputMask" display="text" />
                        </h:panelGrid>

                    </p:outputPanel>
                </p:tab> 

            </p:tabView>


        </p:panel>


    </h:form>

</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

i have addListener method in p:ajax in p:selectOneMenu.This method is working in this way;
you are selecting one object from selectOneMenu and this object is put in the last index of the list filling selectOneMenu ,the object in the last index of the list is put in the index of selected object.I mean you are selecting an object and the index of this object in the list is 2.In total there are five objects in the list ,let we say.selected object whose index is 2 is put in index 4 of the list.The object in index 4 of the list is put in index 2 of the list.I am sorry for my english.The aim of this addListener method,selectOneMenu displays the last item of the list as selected always.Whichever object you select,IT DISPLAYS THE LAST ITEM OF THE LIST.Therefore due to this method , the object i selected is put in the last of the list and it displays as selected to user.The method works fine.
But when page is loaded first , the last item of the list is shown as selected in p:selectOneMenu ,i want "please select" to be shown as default."
My bean class is SilYapilandirmaView.java

```
     @ManagedBean
     @ViewScoped
    public class SilYapilandirmaView extends BaseView implements Serializable {


    @ManagedProperty("#{commonService}")
    private CommonService commonService;

    private EshsSertifika seciliEshsSertifika;
    private List<EshsSertifika> eshsSertifikaList;


    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {


  seciliEshsSertifika=new EshsSertifika();
    eshsSertifikaList = (List) commonService.hepsiniGetir(EshsSertifika.class);
     seciliEshsSertifika = eshsSertifikaList.get(eshsSertifikaList.size() - 1);

  }

  public CommonService getCommonService() {
    return commonService;
  }

  public void setCommonService(CommonService commonService) {
    this.commonService = commonService;
}


 public void addListener() {

  if(seciliEshsSertifika ==null)
  {
     return;
  }

    int i = 0;
    for (EshsSertifika eshsSert : eshsSertifikaList) {
        if (seciliEshsSertifika.getId() == eshsSert.getId()) {
            eshsSert = eshsSertifikaList.get(eshsSertifikaList.size() - 1);
            eshsSertifikaList.set(i, eshsSert);
            eshsSertifikaList.set(eshsSertifikaList.size() - 1, seciliEshsSertifika);

            break;

        }
        i++;
    }

    }

    public EshsSertifika getSeciliEshsSertifika() {
    return seciliEshsSertifika;
    }

    public void setSeciliEshsSertifika(EshsSertifika seciliEshsSertifika) {
    this.seciliEshsSertifika = seciliEshsSertifika;
    }



     public List<EshsSertifika> getEshsSertifikaList() {
    return eshsSertifikaList;
     }

     public void setEshsSertifikaList(List<EshsSertifika> EshsSertifikaList) {
    this.eshsSertifikaList = EshsSertifikaList;
    }
     }
```

When i added following code in init() method ,my code is working perfectly! 
    seciliEshsSertifika=null;

```
public void init() {


  seciliEshsSertifika=new EshsSertifika();
    eshsSertifikaList = (List) commonService.hepsiniGetir(EshsSertifika.class);
     seciliEshsSertifika = eshsSertifikaList.get(eshsSertifikaList.size() - 1);

seciliEshsSertifika=null;
  }
```

when page is loaded, "please select one" is visible in p:selectOneMenu,but i don't want to make "seciliEshsSertifika" object equal to null.,is there anybody else coming up with another solution?

Comment: you need to put in the first position of the list and object with this text. without value. you also can do it sth like this: http://primefaces-rocks.appspot.com/ui/selectOneMenu.jsf

Answer (score 0):

Try this. get the object you want to set the first item. (this example i get the first object in the list)

bean.java

```
EshsSertifika firstItem = eshsSertifikaList.get(0);
```

xhtml

```
<f:selectItem itemLabel="#{eshsSertifika.firstItem.sertifikaKodAdi}" itemValue="#{eshsSertifika.firstItem}" />
```

Comment: but i want this to be displayed  in selectOneMenu when page is loaded         <f:selectItem itemLabel="Please select one" itemValue="#{null}"/>